Moving Recorded Videos Form Zoom App To any other cloud like Youtube or google drive
i have a Zoom account the limited with 5 GB storage and I need to share some of the recorded videos with my students
to if i try to download and reupload every single video every time this will be hard and need time
so i need a tool to make it automatic so this process doesn't take any time
i have tried so many things but it ends up not working or I pay a lot of money for it
I have tried Zapier and other things like it to Automate the Process
